# How to show only specific node level in d3 tree layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to show only specific level of children in a d3 tree layout on load. So far, all the nodes (children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc) are displayed, and it makes the page look weird.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//build tree
function BuildVerticaLTree(treeData, treeContainerDom) {
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 };
    var width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0, duration = 750;
    var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
        //.size([height, width]);
    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
    var svg = d3.select(treeContainerDom).append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 1000)
        .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1,3]).on("zoom", redraw))
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

    //necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
    zm.translate([350, 20]);

    root = treeData;

    update(root);
    function update(source) {
        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
            links = tree.links(nodes);
        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });
        // Declare the nodes…
        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
        // Enter the nodes.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
            }).on("click", nodeclick);
        nodeEnter.append("circle")
         .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "steelblue" : "#00c13f"; })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
        //.attr("r", 10)
        //.style("fill", "#fff");
        nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
        // Transition nodes to their new position.
        //horizontal tree
        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
        nodeUpdate.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);


        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
            .remove();
        nodeExit.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6);
        nodeExit.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
        // Update the links…
        // Declare the links…
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });
        // Enter the links.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")

            .attr("d", function (d) {
                var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
            });
        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);


        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
            })
            .remove();

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
        });

    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function nodeclick(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }
}

var treeData =
{
"name": "OLOGBOTTSERE EYINMINSAREN",
"children": [
  {
      "name": "UWAKUN THE UWANGUE",
      "children": [
        {
            "name": "DIARE",
             "children": [
               {
                    "name": "OKOROBOYO",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "EMMANUEL",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "OGBAWA",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "ADDIN",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "EDEMA",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "DIDEN",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "NEBULIAGHANJE",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "EGHERUN",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "WILFRED",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "ANDREW",
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ITENE",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "AUGUSTUS",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "OMADELI",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "TOSAN",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "RHEMA",
                                                    "children": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "UROWOLI",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "WUWUORITSELA",
                                                    "children": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "OFEORITSE",
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "ABUGEWA",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "OMAYELI",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "EMMANUEL",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "ORITSEWEYINMI",
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ALBERT",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ROSALINE",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "TIMA",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "EDUN",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "CHARLES",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "HENRY",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "TSHEWO",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ENEDOKPE",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ORITSHELA",
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "AZARIA",
                                                            "children": []
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "AYETU",
                                                    "children": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ORITSENEMI",
                                                    "children": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "JANET",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "GODWIN",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ALEXANDER",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AKPAKE",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WELEKE",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "ALICE",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "HANNAH",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "GLADYS",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "KWAME",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MENE",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "ADA",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ERIC",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "KUDIEYIN",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "JOS",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "TOYE",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ROSE",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "SAMUEL",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "MEYIWA",
                                                    "children": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "HELEN",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "MONSIGNOR",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "UKEGBULI",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METSERUNEKPE",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "ABIJOKE",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DUPE",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "UYAULITSEMI",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "PIGIN",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SAMUEL",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "REV. FELIX",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "THOMPSON",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "CHRISTIANA",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "UROWOLI",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
               }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
]
};
BuildVerticaLTree(treeData, "#genealogy-tree");
});
```

Currently, it shows all the nodes on load, but I want it to show just 4 or 5 levels down. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Like the example above you can use:

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

To collapse things after the second level - i.e. you will only display the root and the children at the first level.

If you want to start with the next level down you would amend that to:

```
root.children[0].children.forEach(collapse);
```

For the root plus two levels.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

By a collapse function:

```js
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
```

So you can invoke it by adding

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

just before the main update(root) function.

Look at the collapsible d3 treeview example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way I can determine the number of level to show on page load? Let's say I have the tree with up to 5 levels, can I just show only 3 levels on page load?